# Difficulty using recent update to core.matrix.stats

Tags: matrix, clojure, statistics

Following github I added this dependency to my leiningen project file:

```
[net.mikera/core.matrix.stats "0.5.0"]
```

Then in my clojure code I use this:

```
(use 'core.matrix.stats)
```

The result is this:

```
FileNotFoundException Could not locate core/matrix/stats__init.class or core/matrix/stats.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
```

I examined the lein .m2/respository directory and the file core/matrix/stats-0.5.0.jar is there and does contain stats.clj. I re-did lein deps, but still the file-not-found exception. Has anyone else had this difficulty? I could use Incanter, but for this simple project core.matrix.stats is enough.

Answer (score 2):

[Looking at the sources](https://github.com/clojure-numerics/core.matrix.stats/blob/develop/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/matrix/stats.clj), the namespace seems to be `clojure.core.matrix.stats`, so try this:

```
(use 'clojure.core.matrix.stats)
```

(And yes, the README seems to be outdated.)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The 'readme' is outdated. This works. Thank you kindly.